# tqdm progress bar with Docker logs

Tags: python, docker, tqdm

I am using [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/) to display various progress bars for my Python console application. For the production deployment of the applications, I use Docker.

The progress bars work fine when running a Python application in a terminal. However, when Dockerized and the terminal output is accessed through `docker logs` the progress bar does not function because as far as I understand it is not an interactive terminal. Although it looks like the progress gets rendered if `docker logs` is dumped after the progress bar have completed, but not sure if there are some other conditions for this to happen (output buffering?).

I would like to modify my `tqdm` behavior so that

- It detects when it is run in non-interactive Dockerised environment
- Instead of displaying interactive progress bar, it will log completion statements (10% done, X iterations/s) regularly

This way the progress durations and such would be more accessible when running the application in production.

What would be the way to attach such a custom behavior to `tqdm`?

Comment: I'm not sure you would attach that behavior to `tqdm` itself; I think you would modify your code so that if it's running on a tty it uses tqdm, and if it's *not* running on a tty  you just log plain text messages.

Comment: `tqdm` already has special behaviro for Jupyter notebook through `auto` import. I do not see how this would be different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can recognize if your process is running in non-interactive docker environment according to absence of TERM environment variable.

```
# interactive environment
$ docker run --rm -it centos:7 env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=8c810e490671
TERM=xterm
HOME=/root

# non-interactive environment
$ docker run --rm  centos:7 env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=e267f2ba0f8f
HOME=/root
```

Consider this fact in your script and in case of non-interactive environment use `total` parameter of tqdm or `disable` it:

> total : int or float, optional
>
> The number of expected iterations. If unspecified, len(iterable) is
> used if possible. If float("inf") or as a last resort, only basic
> progress statistics are displayed (no ETA, no progressbar). If gui is
> True and this parameter needs subsequent updating, specify an initial
> arbitrary large positive number, e.g. 9e9.

> disable : bool, optional
>
> Whether to disable the entire progressbar wrapper [default: False]. If
> set to None, disable on non-TTY.

https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/#parameters

**Update:**

It looks like TERM env variable in non-interactive environment has the value "dumb"

```
docker run --rm  centos:7 bash -c 'echo "${TERM}"'
dumb
```

Comment: Thank you Slava. [I converted this recipe to a Python package here](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/tqdm-loggable).